# Apache derby - SELECT * FROM tablename dont work

Tags: sql, derby

When i execute SELECT * FROM tablename generate that erorr :
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table/View 'tablename' does not exist.
but if i run that sql command
SELECT * FROM "tablename" the sql run without problems why.

Answer (score 1):

This is an aspect of the SQL standard known as "delimited identifiers".

Table names, column names, and other objects are things that you can give names to in your database.

The SQL standard says that, if you aren't particular about the upper/lower case of your object names, you can just specify the names without quotation marks, and your database will process them in a case-insensitive manner (typically, by converting an unquoted object name into the all-upper-case version of that name).

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(c1 INT, c2 CHAR(10));

INSERT INTO MyTable (C1, C2) VALUES (42, 'Bryan');

SELECT c2 FROM MYTABLE;
```

Since you didn't specify any object names in quotation marks, all of these examples work fine, because `mytable`, `MyTable`, and `MYTABLE` are all the same, when they aren't in quotation marks.

But if you specify your object names in quotation marks, then you have to get things **exactly right**:

```
CREATE TABLE "MyCaseSensitiveTable" (c1 int, c2 char(10));

INSERT INTO MyCaseInsensitiveTable (c1, c2) values (64, 'a nice age');
```

In this case, your `INSERT` statement will be rejected, because `"MyCaseSensitiveTable"` is **different** than `MyCaseSensitiveTable`.

Delimited identifiers bring other advantages:

1. You can use otherwise-reserved keywords from the SQL language as table names, so you can create a table named `"TABLE"` if you want.
2. You can use various special characters in your database object names.

Personally, I try never to use delimited identifiers, because I think they make my programs hard to read. But they are a completely legitimate part of the SQL standard and they are widely used.

But, the bottom line is: if you're going to put your database object names in quotation marks, you have to put them in quotation marks **all the time**, and you have to give the name **exactly** the same each time, but if you don't use quotation marks for your database object names, they will be treated in a case-insensitive manner.

Comment: Thank You, your answer is very clear, helpful and informative. Yes when i created my table i used the quotation marks so that's why i got thats error. thank you again.